# SQLAlchemy failing to catch not null constraint when primary key true

Tags: python, null, sqlalchemy, constraints, primary-key

Previously testing would raise an Exception when passing in None for

```
Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

Now when I change it to be primary key true, it no longer raises an Exception

```
Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

I have tried a separate CheckConstraint() for NOT NULL but it still doesn't complain.

How do I get it to complain again when I try to commit a None/Null value for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy [defaults to `autoincrement=True` for primary key `Integer` columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement) - therefore in your second case, `NULL` is never actually inserted, and that's why the constraint is still satisfied.

Setting `autoincrement=False` should get you the behavior you want:

```
Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'll continue to try to waddle my way through this. Also, thanks for the link.